# Can you have a Math.Random function and use a selection sort to sort it out?

Tags: java, math, sorting, random

Can you have a Math.Random function and use a selection sort to sort it out?

Comment: a bit more explanation please.

Comment: @Lucy: Could you be more specific on your question? Yes there is a Math.Random in java. What do you want to sort from where?

Comment: @Lucy So I understand, that you want to create a list of random numbers. And then sort them?

Comment: Answering the **exact** question asked: No. `Math.Random` returns a single value, and therefore there's nothing to sort.

Comment: @Lucy wants for you to show her how to do a selection sort in Java.

Comment: @Lucy: Read over this [article](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Selection_sort); it might help clarify your question.

Comment: @Marcelo: I know that. Lucy didn't ask that, though, and didn't say what should be sorted (an array, a collection). Lucy should edit to ask a real question if Lucy wants to get an answer.

Comment: `To sort it out` - to sort out what? The Math.Random function? Well, that is not possible - how would you sort a single thing?

Answer (score 0):

You could even create directly a random sorted collection if you want. For instance you could take random numbers in non overlapping increasing ranges, a simple implementation that comes to my mind is using each (predecessor + a minor quantity) as the minimum for the range in which you take the next random number.

Or even a straightforward code like this :

```
double[] tab = new double[ N ];
tab[ 0 ] = Math.random();
for( int i=1; i < N; i ++ ) 
   tab[ i ] = tab[ i - 1 ] + Math.random();
```

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: I mean like instead of having something like int [] = { 32. 45, 454, 232, 2}; I was wondering is there a way you can use a Math. random function that gives you random numbers and you use the selection sort to sort it out.

Comment: @Snicolas: You mean [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)?

Comment: @Lucy, why do you care about the algorithm to sort it out ?

Comment: what do you mean. I just want to use the selection sort to sort out the random numbers its for an assignment I have to do.

Comment: @Lucy What do you want to know exactly? "Yes, it is possible"?

Comment: And what did you try so far to implement the selection sort algorithm ?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question asked (because there is no actual question). I posted a comment to the original question that does so, though. Please don't try and answer this type of question - it's nonsense, and answers encourage others to post similar non-questions and add a lot of clutter here. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
final int intCount = 128;
final int intSize = 1024;

int myArray[] = new int[intCount];
for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++) {
    myArray[i] = java.lang.Math.random() * intSize;
}

// TODO: Your selection sort code here
```

Comment: @Lucy Is that what you wanted. I think we all are having problems understanding what you mean.

Comment: Please don't answer posts like this that are not real questions. It not only will probably be closed soon, but it encourages people to post other similar non-questions and adds lots of clutter; that clutter makes SO less useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of

```
  int [] j = { 32. 45, 454, 232, 2};
```

you can use

```
  Random r = new Random();      
  int [] j = { r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt() };
```

Comment: Please don't answer posts like this that are not real questions. It not only will probably be closed soon, but it encourages people to post other similar non-questions and adds lots of clutter; that clutter makes SO less useful. Thanks.

Comment: I did think it was a genuine question after reading her comment: <quote>I mean like instead of having something like int [] = { 32. 45, 454, 232, 2}; I was wondering is there a way you can use a Math. random function that gives you random numbers and you use the selection sort to sort it out.</quote>

Comment: Then you should have asked her to improve the question first. As is, it's totally useless to anyone in the future, because it's not searchable. Instead of trying to improve your own rep by posting an "I'm guessing" answer, you should have tried to improve the usefulness of the question for others by asking her to clarify it first.

Comment: Since you have already decided my motive was to increase my rep (contradicting my claim that I was trying to help the OP) there is nothing more to say. Go ahead and downvote, you have the power.